# Git push succeeded even Travis failed

Tags: django, git, github, travis-ci

I have integrated `Travis CI tool` into my `Django` project.

The problem is that my `push` to origin works even Travis testing has failed.

Here is my commit log :

```
* c5c9e57 (HEAD -> feature/init, origin/feature/init) Update requirements(dev) : selenium
* 2c8f6ee Install Travis in slack
* 75c8ccb Init travis.yml
* 54fa188 Create Makefile : migrate
* d211af7 Add chacha_dabnag in INSTALLED_APPS
* 3e5601d Install debug_toolbar and django_extension
* d2a8780 Scaffold settings
* 2d63194 Update .gitignore : database files
* 2bfc7c5 Init project : chacha_dabang
* 4466f58 Init : requirements
```

My branch list :

```
  develop                     e3a8499 [origin/develop] Initial commit
* feature/init                c5c9e57 Update requirements(dev) : selenium
  master                      e3a8499 [origin/master] Initial commit
  remotes/origin/HEAD         -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/develop      e3a8499 Initial commit
  remotes/origin/feature/init c5c9e57 Update requirements(dev) : selenium
  remotes/origin/master       e3a8499 Initial commit
```

My `.travis.yml` file :

```
 language: python
 python:
   - "3.4"
   - "3.5"
 # command to install dependencies
 install:
   - pip install -r requirements/development.txt
```

`Travis` build-history window :
[image]

`Github` commit log:
[image]

As you can see here, `2c8f6ee Install Travis in slack` and `c5c9e57 Update requirements(dev) : selenium` failed at `Travis`, but it already merged in `github`. Why does this happen?

Comment: You are free to ignore the advise Travis CI gives, and just merge the commit despite tests that fail. If this does not answer your question, please update your question to make it more specific.

Comment: Are you trying to implement automatic release cycle? Where if travis succeeds your feature branch is merged into release branch?

Answer (score 0):

Of course
`$ git push` works,
and its not depend if `Travis` is integrated to your project or not.

Notice, that `Travis` gives you feedback, and now it is your decision:
 1. merge this changes to master branch
 2. create a pull request if your project is a fork
 or
 3. fix your code, failing tests, other bugs and then back to 1. or 2.

I see, you are using a good practice to first push your changes to custom branches (not master branch). In this case the broken tests do not harm the main project.

Comment: But, what I want to do is to prevent branch from pushing to origin(in this case, prevent `feature/init` branch from merging into `origin/featre/init`)  if problems are detected by `Travis`..... is it possible?

Comment: If `feature/init` means branch on your local PC and `origin/feature/init` is branch on your github account. It is impossible.
`Travis` retrieves information from your github account which I guessing is your `origin` (github.com/rightx2/proj)? not from local PC.
  
`local-PC/proj->push->github/rightx2/proj->send-to-travis->travis/proj-feedback-back-to-github-> red or green icon on github`.
  
Another solution could be create a new github account only for checking `Travis` successes or  
(not recommended -- brutal) `git reset --hard last_good_commit` and `git push --force origin/branch`.